# Changes are not reflectiong to apk <Ionic>

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cross-platform, ionic-native

I was following the [Moodle Documentation](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Setting_up_your_development_environment_for_Moodle_Mobile_2#Install_a_browser_for_development)  where i downloaded the repo and npm run setup which helps to setup project.
Then i used Ionic serve --browser chrome
it opens the app in chrome browser and also loads all Js files.
I can able to make changes and in Js files and i can see the changes reflected in browser.
When I’m trying to convert it into apk by using
npm run ionic:build – --prod
cordova run android
these commands helps in getting APK bt the changes i made in JS files are not reflecting

Comment: Please clarify more, if you temove the build and do a rebuild, wouldn't it build the correct apk?

Comment: Hi, remove 'www' and 'platform/android' and rebuild the app. That should do the trick

Comment: did you try me solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use this command: `ionic cordova build android`

This will build the project completely and will solve your problem.

If it didn't work, follow these steps:

```
ionic cordova platform rm android
```

then:

```
ionic cordova platform add android
```

then:

```
ionic cordova build android
```